# D3: Passing object array data to a barchart on mouseover

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

Working with two charts in D3. I have a pie chat displaying parent data regarding a budget. When the user mouses over a pie slice, I am trying to push that slice's array data to a bar chart.

My data is setup like so:

```
 {"Department":"Judiciary",
    "Funds1415":317432,
    "Fundsb":"317.4",
    "annual": [ 282,288,307,276,276,298,309,317,317 ]  
  },
```

I'm trying to use this to pass the annual array to the barchart:

```
 path.on('mouseover', function(d) { 
...
  bars.selectAll('rect').transition().attr("y", function(d) { return h - d.data.annual /125; });
  bars.selectAll('rect').transition().attr("height", function(d) { return d.data.annual / 125; });
});
```

And here's the barchart I'm trying to send it to:

```
var bars = svg.selectAll("rect")
   .data(budget)
   .enter()
   .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "barchart")
    .attr("transform", "translate(26,109)")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return color2(i);
    })
   .attr('class', 'barchart')
   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * 14;  
})
   .attr("width", 12)
    .attr("y", 100)
    .attr("height", 100);
```

Link to full code here: 
http://jsbin.com/zayopecuto/1/edit?html,js,output

Everything 'seems' to be working, except the data either isn't passing or it isn't updating the bar chart.

I've been banging my head up against this for a couple of days, to no avail. Originally I was thinking of placing the annual data in separate arrays and just transitioning from data source to data source on mouseover, but that seems backward and unnecessary.

Comment: I believe you need to pass in the corresponding data on mouseover, i.e the data object for the current arc and create or update the bar chart based on the `annual` array. But in the code above you seem to be setting up the bar once and on hover, you are setting a constant height to the bars.

Comment: There are several problems in your  code. As a start, but all barchart elements (axes and rects) in one g, and class it as "barchart". Remove all "barchart" classing from the rest of the elements. Apply the transform to the "g" itself.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'm still getting a 'data undefined' error on the mouseover. I'm somewhat new to D3 and am not entirely sure of the syntax to pass in the individual arc's array.

Comment: Instead of pre-drawing the bar chart and having it hidden, would it be better to create it as a function, then have the mouse-over call the function with the corresponding data array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your selector is wrong.  `bars` is already a collection of rects, so you can't re-select the rects.  Second, you haven't bound "updated" data to those rects.  So, with this in mind, it becomes:

```
bars
  .data(d.data.annual)
  .transition()
  .attr("height", function(d) { 
    return d / 125; 
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) { 
    return h - d /125; 
  });
```

Here's an updated [example](http://jsbin.com/liceyefamo/2/edit).

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your code and comment is that, you have data points for your donut chart and each data object contains a property called 'annual' which you want to use as a input data for the bar chart.

1. You should be calling a separate function to plot your bar chart passing it the annual data array.
2. Clear the existing bar chart on 'mouseout' event, so that a new bar chart can be plotted on the next 'mouseover' event. You can use jQuery `empty()` function for clearing out the chart container.